# adb serverのリスニングアドレスを指定する方法はありますか？

Tags: android, adb

標題のとおり adb server の待ち受けアドレスの指定方法を知りたいと思っております。

使用しているSDKは android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tar.gz

通常、下記を行うと 127.0.0.1:5037 で adb server が待ち受けていると思います。

```
$ adb start-server
```

これをホストマシンの全ネットワークインターフェース、
あるいは指定したネットワークインタフェースで待ち受けることはできますでしょうか？

行いことは次の[4.]です。 
1. 今、ホストマシン(192.168.0.1)がありそこで Androidエミュレータが動いています。
2. そのエミュレータ内側で動くサーバプログラムがあります。それは 0.0.0.0:10000 で待ち受けているとします。
3. ホストマシンから次の操作でそのサーバプログラムに接続することができます。

```
$ adb foward tcp:10000 tcp:10000
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 10000
```

4. そのサーバプログラムに別マシン(192.168.0.3)から同じ様に接続したいのです。

```
$ telnet 192.168.0.1 10000
```

「$ adb -a start-server」ではダメでした。
またホストはLinxuマシンなので iptables で 127.0.0.1 に転送しようとしましたが、知識不足のためかうまくいきませんでした。

何らかの手段をご存じの方いましたらご教示いただければと思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己フォローです。
別フォーラムで回答いただいたsshのポートフォワードで対応できました。

Comment: 解決済みであることを示すために、この回答を自己承認(チェックをクリックする)していただけますか？(そうしないと、サイト的に未解決の問題として扱われてしまう)

Comment: ご連絡ありがとうございます。m(_ _)m